# How do I specify an external zipkin collector in istio?

Tags: istio, zipkin, distributed-tracing

I want to use stackdriver trace as a back end for distributed tracing in istio. I installed Docker on the VM of GCP, and run the image of zipkin-gcp.

```
docker run -d -p 9411:9411 -e STORAGE_TYPE=stackdriver -e STACKDRIVER_PROJECT_ID=my-project openzipkin/zipkin-gcp
```

Then, according to the official documentation, I configured istio to send spans to this VM.

```
istioctl manifest apply --set values.tracing.enabled=true --set values.tracing.provider=zipkin --set values.global.tracer.zipkin.address=10.128.0.30:9411 --set values.pilot.traceSampling=100.0
```

However, no trace was displayed in the stackdriver trace.

To isolate the problem, I stopped zipkin-gcp and checked if packets were being sent with tcpdump.

```
tcpdump -i eth0 dst port 9411
```

As a result, it was found that nothing was sent. I have confirmed port 9411 connectivity from the kubernetes cluster to the VM.

How do I send a trace to an external zipkin server with istio?

Comment: Hi, did You forward the `9411` port to the docker network? Seems like Your VM might be reachable but not the container.

Comment: well, I think 9411 port is forwarded due to `-p 9411:9411`. And I have confirmed reachability from the k8s cluster to the VM.
I threw an HTTP request from the k8s cluster to 9411 and confirmed that the packet appeared in tcpdump. I think it means that there is TCP connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally figured out what could be the cause of this issue:

The install option:

`--set values.tracing.provider=zipkin --set values.global.tracer.zipkin.address`

requires `<zipkin-collector-service>.<zipkin-collector-namespace>:9411` according to [istio](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/zipkin/#before-you-begin) documentation. While You have just IP address and port of external server.

This most likely means that the install option requires existing name that is in istio service mesh registry.

So if Your zipkin collector is outside cluster We need to add `ServiceEntry`, `VirtualService` and maybe `DestinationRule` and so the external service can be used within mesh.

You can follow [istio](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/) documentation to see how to create these objects for external service. [Here](https://istiobyexample.dev/external-services/) is another guide.

After that We need to update the tracer address value with the `VirtualService` as an endpoint.

```
--set values.global.tracer.zipkin.address=zipkin-external-virtualservice.egress-zipkin-namespace:9411
```

Hope this helps.